# Finding elements through UIautomator

Tags: android, reactjs, automation, appium-android, android-uiautomator

Friends,

I need help in finding `XPATHs` of various elements on a `CANVAS` (selection of seats in a theater) seats arranged in rows 
(a1... a25, b1.. b25, and so on). I used `UIAutomator` to find these elements, unfortunately, i am unable to find the
elements of a particular selected seat.

Where as rest of elements i can able to find through `UIAutomator`. I am doing android real device automation through `USB`.

Much appreciate your help.

Not able to find the seat selection elements

Answer (score 0):

> Using xpath is not recommended in appium. If possible ask your developer to add automation id in the element.

I suggest you to use **Appium Desktop Inspector** instead of **uiautomatorviewer** as it will suggest you automation id (if any) and unique xpath in the top right side. You can also interact with the app from Appium Desktop inspector. You can also record test.

Comment: Thanks for your response I tried both ui automator and appium desk top inspector In both I m not able to view the elements ( as per my knowledge it's a canvas seat / scroll view window ) Note : facing issue in finding seat elements and rest all elements I can able to get index, text , resource id I am not able to attach screen shot

Comment: If xpath is not showing or element node is not visible in xml file the only solution is to talk with developer to change their design so that the element can be detected in xml. Earlier I had the same issue and developer fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks Suban
I will check with developer

Comment: you are welcome. In my case dynamic list element was not showing in xml.

Comment: When i discuss with developer he said like naming, id or index value cant be allocate to each seat bcz the seat layout contains more than 10000 seats, also he said like for seat layout they used react map

Answer (score 0):

contact your developer and tell them you can't recognize particular element. Definitely they will help